# Objective-C trying to create a label for each item in NSArray - Not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array that looks like the image attached

[image]

and what I am trying to do is the following:

- Run a foreach for this NSArray
- Create a label for each item in the array (so 3 Division Labels, 3 Project Labels, 3 WorkOrder Labels and 3 Assemble Labels)

I have the following code:

```
int counter = 0;
    for (id object in _theParamenterArray) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Assemble"];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:label];

        UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Division"];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:labelTwo];

        UILabel *labelThree = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Project"];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:labelThree];

        UILabel *labelFour = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        label.text = [object objectForKey:@"WorkOrder"];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:labelFour];
        counter++;
    }
```

My issue with this code is that it only creates 4 labels in total and the data is the last item in the array, so it appears its overriding the values. My question how do I fix this? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Are you sure your loop is executing three times?  I note that the array shown in the debugger and the array in your code have different names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your issue is assigning text and font to `label` 4 times, try this:

```
int counter = 0;
    for (id object in _theParamenterArray) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        label.text = [object objectForKey:@"Assemble"];
        [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:label];

        UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        labelTwo.text = [object objectForKey:@"Division"];
        [labelTwo setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:labelTwo];

        UILabel *labelThree = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        labelThree.text = [object objectForKey:@"Project"];
        [labelThree setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:labelThree];

        UILabel *labelFour = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 30*counter + 10, 200, 200)];
        labelFour.text = [object objectForKey:@"WorkOrder"];
        [labelFour setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [self.view addSubview:labelFour];
        counter++;
    }
```

It would help to see the code for the array.

Answer (score 4):

you set text only for "label" variable :) It's a Copy/Paste bug :)
rename label -> labelTwo, labelThree, labelFour for lines:

```objc
label.text = [object objectForKey:@"WorkOrder"];
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
```